# Interfacing with MongoDB in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

Is there function to throw query mongoDB like this `$this->db->query($query)` because I want  to create mongoDB executor in codeigniter so if I type this query like this:

```
db.users.find({age:33})
```

... codeigniter throw that query directly to mongodb server or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [MongoDB PHP Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)'s [`MongoDB::command()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php) for passing such database commands to the mongodb server.

In CodeIgniter there are a few community-built MongoDB libraries you can use. Since I checked almost all of them, take my advise and use [CodeIgniter MongoDB Active Record](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2). Here's a sample code:

```
<?php
// Somewhere in your model, controller, etc.

// Load MongoDB library
$this->load->library('mongo_db');

// Query MongoDB: Active document library usage example
$docs = $this->mongo_db->where('age', '33')->get('collection_name_here');  

// Query MongoDB: Command usage example
$docs = $this->mongo_db->command(array(
    'geoNear'    => 'buildings', 
    'near'       => array(53.228482, -0.547847), 
    'num'        => 10, 
    'nearSphere' => TRUE,
));

// Theme results, pass to the view, etc.
```

Here are a few other libraries around that you might want to use alongside the active record one:

- [CodeIgniter MongoDB Session Library](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-session)
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB IonAuth Authentication Library](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-ionauth)
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB REST Server Library](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-restserver)
- [CodeIgniter MongoDB Base Model](https://github.com/sepehr/ci-mongodb-base-model)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try. I want to create mongoDB executor like this [https://github.com/zacksyah/sql_executor](https://github.com/zacksyah/sql_executor) I already created SQL executor and I want too create that app with mongoDB so if we input the query like `db.user.find({age:33})` or we input query like this `{age:33}` php directly throw that query to server & return the result. The app will be like phpmyadmin for SQL and rockmongo for mongoDB, but my app will be make still very simple

Comment: Get the query from user input, pass it to MongoDB::command(), and output the themed results.